# UrlRewriteFilter redirects to wrong login.html page with FORM authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, web-applications, url-rewriting

I have a webapp setup in Tomcat 7 that needs to leverage form-based security. This webapp also uses `org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter` to rewrite URLs.

For reference, here's the relevant portion of the `web.xml` file in my `webapps/.../WEB-INF` directory:

```
<security-role>
   <role-name>foo.pr</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
   <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
      <!-- Define the context-relative URL(s) to be protected -->
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <!-- If you list http methods, only those methods are protected -->
   </web-resource-collection>
   <auth-constraint>
      <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
      <role-name>all.foo</role-name>
   </auth-constraint>
  <!-- <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint> -->
</security-constraint>

 <login-config>
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
   <realm-name>Authentication</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
     <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
     <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>60</param-value> <!-- -1, 0, or something like 60 -->
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
    <param-value>INFO</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>statusEnabledOnHosts</param-name>
    <param-value>localhost, 192.168.188.*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I try to access the webapp, the security is bypassed, and the `login.html` file is passed through the `UrlRewriteFilter`. I don't want this behavior; I want it to get the `login.html` file that is in `webapps/ROOT`.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated. I may be misunderstanding something fundamental. If you need to see any other files, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although this isn't the *perfect* answer, it solved my issue.

I struggled for quite awhile to figure out how to have the user go to the login.html file before the URL was rewritten, but I couldn't figure it out. So what I did instead is I added an exception for the login.html file and error.html files in the URLRewriter configuration file so that they aren't re-written.

I'd still rather have the web app send the user to the security rather than to the filter, but I'll take what I can get.